# how to fill dates "holes" in table?

Tags: sas

I guess my question was not as clear as I thought.
I will do by best to explain my problem:

I have a table of customers and dates.
I used the LAG function to retrieve previous dates to figure out whether 
there are "holes" in dates:

```
    Customer        Prev_date                       Date                    Missing_ind
    1               01dec2004:00:00:00              01jan2005:00:00:00             0
    1               01jan2005:00:00:00              01feb2005:00:00:00             0
    1               01feb2005:00:00:00              01apr2005:00:00:00             1
    2               01dec2004:00:00:00              01jan2005:00:00:00             0
    2               01jan2005:00:00:00              01feb2005:00:00:00             0
    2               01feb2005:00:00:00              01mar2005:00:00:00             0
    2               01mar2005:00:00:00              01jun2005:00:00:00             2
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

As you can see, in line 3 there's 1 month missing for customer 1 (mar2005)
and in line 7 there are 2 months missing for customer 2 (apr2005, may2005).

There is an indicator telling me how many missing months are for every customer (Missing_ind)

What I need to do is,
complete the missing months for all customers in table, whether to the exact table,
or insert rows to a new table.

How can it be done?

Thank you for helping me out,

Gal.

Comment: What constitutes a "missing month" for a customer?  Is it based on a single calendar range for all customers **or** is it based on the range of values for **each** customer?

Answer (score 1):

This actually is a different question now, which is pretty easy to solve.

```
data have;
input Customer (prev_date date) (:datetime17.);
format prev_date date datetime19.;
datalines; 
    1               01dec2004:00:00:00              01jan2005:00:00:00            
    1               01jan2005:00:00:00              01feb2005:00:00:00            
    1               01feb2005:00:00:00              01apr2005:00:00:00            
    2               01dec2004:00:00:00              01jan2005:00:00:00            
    2               01jan2005:00:00:00              01feb2005:00:00:00            
    2               01feb2005:00:00:00              01mar2005:00:00:00            
    2               01mar2005:00:00:00              01jun2005:00:00:00   
;;;;
run;
data want;
set have;
missing_months = intck('dtMonth',prev_date,date)-1;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply,
but  I don't think your solution helps me gain what I want.

As  you  can see,
I already found a way to know if there are missing months.
For example,  I know customer 2 is missing march, may and june.

Question is:
How do I add the missing months for customer 2?
How do I add missing months for each customer in table?

Thanks again,
Gal

Comment: I don't think you are explaining what you want, then.  The output table from data=have is the table including all 'missing months', including a variable to differentiate them.

Comment: @user2518751 Edited to create approximately the table you ask for in your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

As you already have determined the number of missing months in between two dates, the solution can be done with a simple do loop and the intnx function.

```
data missing_dates (keep=customer missing_date );
 set dates;
 format missing_date datetime17.;
 missing_date = prev_date;
 do i=1 to missing_ind by 1;
  missing_date = intnx('dtmonth',missing_date,1,'b');
  output;
 end;
run;
```